# Wordpress Header Image

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to edit the header of my website to use my logo in the header. In the header.php file under the "Display Logo Image or Site Title" code  here is what I have after putting in the image link:

```
$options = get_option('zeefocus_options');
            if ( isset($options['themeZee_general_logo']) and    $options['themeZee_general_logo'] <> "" ) : ?>
                <img class="logo-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/02WuoWa.png" alt="Auto-Platre" /></a>
```

I saved and uploaded the file, but the webpage is still the same. Do I need to edit anything in the Wordpress admin?

Answer (score 0):

Without more info this question is kind of hard to answer but here are a few things to try:

- Clear your cache if you have it enabled
- Your theme might have a built in header option, in which case you can upload the image to directly through the theme settings